# Can Video Files Be Stored in MCAP Format?

Tags: python, video-processing, video-encoding, mcap

Hello Stack Overflow Community,

I am currently exploring MCAP files for a project and am exploring the capabilities of this format. I'm particularly interested in understanding whether it's possible to store video files within MCAP containers.

From my understanding, MCAP is a container file format for multimodal log data, but I'm unsure if it supports video data integration. My questions are:

1. Can MCAP files store video data? If so, are there any specific formats or encodings that are compatible?
2. What are the best practices for integrating video into MCAP files, and how can I ensure efficient playback and synchronization with other data types?
3. Are there any tools or libraries particularly well-suited for working with video data in MCAP files?

I would greatly appreciate any insights, experiences, or resources you could share regarding this query.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: A counter-question: Why would you need to do this? What's your end goal?

Comment: I have a client that needs it this way as he is working only with MCAP files.